# Little confusion about dc motors

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor

So for whatever reason I'm having a little bit of a problem understanding why every dc motor explanation says the current switches after every segment in the armature.

I mean the current is going to flow the same way since the power source isn't being reversed right? So when they say it switches after the break between segments is it because the armature is just at a different position in relation to the magnets or is the current really reversing?

Answer (score 3):

Power to the armature coils is reversed because the brushes and commutator act as a reversing switch. Consider a simple DC motor with one winding and two commutator segments. When the armature rotates 180°, each segment contacts the brushes on the *opposite* side than it did at 0°, so current passes through the coil in the opposite direction.

[Current in DC motor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/motdc.html)

[image]

Practical motors need at least 3 segments (and coils) to ensure startup from any position. Larger motors may have many more commutator segments, but the commutator switching action is the same.

In the example below, all the coils on the upper side are getting current in one direction (relative to start and end of each winding), while those on the lower side get it in the opposite direction. Each winding's polarity changes as the positive (or negative) brush goes from the segment connected to the start of the winding to the segment at the end of the winding.

[image]

Comment: Wait, think I figured it out. The point of contact is "reversing" but the current is essentially still flowing in the same way. Am I right or still missing something?

Comment: Current always flows in the same direction from one brush to the other, but the connections to the coil reverse as the armature rotates. So it's the _coil_ which has reversed direction, not the current.

Comment: Great that's what I thought but the wording everywhere I read made it confusing. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 for the ilustrations that I didn't found for my answer. @ohmmy now you have it, look carefuly the direction of each segment, you will find out that it is reversing after passing the brush.

Answer (score 0):

There are several separate coils on the armature, each connected to a pair of commutator contacts.  As the coil currently receiving power comes in line with the stator poles, the brushes and commutator switch the power to the next coil, so it will be attracted to the stator poles.  The current is just switched to another coil, not reversed in the same coil.

Answer (score 0):

When the brushes make a short between two segments the current in widning of attached at that segment recirculates - the coil of that segment is short circuited. After the brush leaves that segment, the current begins to flow in the opposite direction as it was before.
So in few words:
1. the current in segment flows CW,
2. then the brush makes ashort circuit, the current is recirculating CW
3. the brush leaves the SC, the current begins to flow in CCW direction

Comment: But isn't the armature basically just a simple path for current to flow through like a wire? This is where my confusion stems. If it's just a straight path for current what makes it flow in the opposite direction as it rotates?